# Is Joomla user management safe enough to handle potential data?

Tags: security, joomla, joomla3.3

How difficult/easy is it to break into Joomla backend & to access the pages which are only set to be accessible by selected Joomla users of the website? Is it safe enough to rely on Joomla's management system?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla specific implementation details and not programming as defined for StackOverflow, it would be better asked on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) where there are lots of Joomla core developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Joomla is quite secure system by itself. Although you have to be careful with third party extensions and always track update news for all components (including core) you have installed and use your judgement about updating them. Usually security issues spotted quite quickly and you have time before succeed attack.

Another thing keep in mind is proactive defense with all possible means you have in hands, this includes `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`, also good idea to restrict ftp access to only local ips and use sftp instead.

Also check out the security extensions around JED, the ones which prevents high level DDoS and extend admin page access protection might be also helpful, usually they are simple modules or plugins.

And yes, do not forget change default username for superuser. And change all passwords ftp/superusers/mysql/htpasswd on regular basis.

Follow this simple rules and you will be fine, at least most of the time you will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

While Joomla security is fairly good, you need to keep up with the patches and, as dmi3y mentioned, you need to watch the third party extensions.

When it comes to information security, nothing is ever perfect. This solution may or may not be appropriate depending on the type of information that you are looking to secure, the number of users accessing it and how you manage the user rights.